# Adjusting sequence square frame size for large screen size

Tags: premiere, keyframes, pro, cc

I am trying to make a square size video of 6:5 ratio for LED display screen. The size of the screen is 12feet x 10feet in pixels it's 13824x11520p.

Do i need my frame size to be this big to make it fit into this large screen OR how do i calculate the ratio to make sure my video will fit perfectly without weird pixelation.

PR ver: CC 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your video to be up-scaled then you need to output at the native resolution of the screen. The physical size doesn't matter, what matters is the pixel dimensions.

However, if the footage is not shot at the native resolution (and I don't think there are many 14K cameras around) you're going to have to resize it to fit. Whether you do that in your edit, or use whatever mechanism the screen has for up-scaling footage depends on a couple of factors:

- can the screen / playback device do its own interpolation, and if so how good is it?
- do you have graphics etc that you want to be crisp? If you're relying on the resolution of the screen to display small graphic elements crisply then you'll want the video that you deliver to be as high resolution as possible.
- can the playback device handle a 14K video stream? Filesize is going to be an issue unless the playback device is pretty fast, and decoding it is going to be taxing for even a powerful machine.

**Best bet**: ask whoever is in charge of the screen. For a screen that large there's going to be an AV person who knows what they're doing. Ask around until you find who can give you specs for what you have to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, stop.

> I am trying to make a square size video of 6:5.

Is your video square or is your video already 6:5?

> The size of the screen is 12feet x 10feet

The screen has a 6:5 ratio, so your video will fit.

But if your video is really square, let's say 1000x1000px, you simply need to crop it.

> pixels it's 13824x11520p.

No, do not resample any video.

@stib already mentioned it. You would need a very powerful computer to playback that. But there are some other elements.

A screen of 12x10 feet is meant to be watched at a distance. Here is an example. You are in a movie theater. The screen can be bigger in size than 12 feet, and you do not use a humungous resolution because you do not need it, not at all. A 4K image is more than enough. Actually a Full HD image is probably good enough. **Not even an IMAX laser projector has the resolution you are talking about**.

---

Any resampling you make will produce... a resampled video. You will not introduce any sharper detail or anything, you will simply turn your video in the exact same video but a heck lot bulkier. The resampling needs to be done in the hardware of the screen. It will probably simply multiply the information to be projected into the different zones of the screen.